# Handle FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException with Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, file-upload

I'm having issues handling fileupload exceptions with Spring.

I have the next multipartResolver:

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    commonsMultipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding(this.defaultEncoding);
    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(this.maxInMemorySize);
    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(this.maxUploadSize);
    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(this.maxUploadSizePerFile);
    return commonsMultipartResolver;
}
```

With the next constant values:

```
webmvc.multipart.maxInMemorySize=10485760 //10MB
webmvc.multipart.maxUploadSize=10485760 //10MB
webmvc.multipart.maxUploadSizePerFile=5242880 //5MB
```

I have the next GlobalExceptionHandler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = MultipartException.class)
    public String handleMultipartException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (ex instanceof MultipartException) {
            final MultipartException mEx = (MultipartException) ex;

            if (ex.getCause() instanceof FileUploadBase.FileSizeLimitExceededException) {
                final FileUploadBase.FileSizeLimitExceededException flEx = (FileUploadBase.FileSizeLimitExceededException) mEx.getCause();
                request.setAttribute("size", flEx.getPermittedSize());
            } else if (ex.getCause() instanceof FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException) {
                final FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException flEx = (FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException) mEx.getCause();
                request.setAttribute("size", flEx.getPermittedSize());
            } else {
                request.setAttribute("error", ex.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("error", ex.getMessage());
        }
        return "forward:/errors.do";
    }
}
```

If I upload a file under 5MB everything works fine, no exceptions fired and the file is uploaded properly.

If I upload a file between 5MB and 10MB, the exception is catched by my GlobalExceptionHandler and the result is shown in my page /errors

However, if I upload a file bigger than 10MB, my GlobalExceptionHandler catches the exception and forwards to /errors, but!, then GlobalExceptionHandler catches again the exception, and keeps doing it until the end of the times.

If I don't missundertand, it seems that my multipart content is processed over and over again by the CommonsMultipartResolver even after GlobalExceptionHandler captured the exception and tried to forward to a complete different page (I tried using redirect instead of forward and the issue remains).

Why doesn't it behave equally in both scenarios? and how can I solve this issue?

I've tried to set `webmvc.multipart.maxInMemorySize=-1` and `webmvc.multipart.maxUploadSize=-1` but then this behaviour ocurrs whenever I upload something bigger than 5MB.

Comment: is there any stack trace in your log ?

Comment: The stack trace shown is for the the exception `FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException` witch is the one being catched in a loop. I don't have it right now, but it describes an error like "your file size is N bytes, and the maximun allowed is X bytes (with N bigger than X)"

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the an exception handler for `MaxUploadSizeExceededException`

```
@ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
    public String handleError(MaxUploadSizeExceededException e, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        .......
    }
```

You can see more here

https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-mvc-how-to-handle-max-upload-size-exceeded-exception/

Comment: The exception fired is not that one, is `FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException` witch like I said, is being captured over and over again. The problem here is the loop behavior, not catching the exception.

Comment: I guess you can change the exception to yours. Did that work?